# T-Sql for getting the fifth row from a table

Tags: sql-server-2008

I found a very strange thing while extracting the 5th row from the table I used the below mentioned query and thought it would be possible by first taking the top 5 rows and then in the outer query take the top 1 after ordering in descending order. But the below query is giving wrong output.

```
select top 1 * 
from 
     (select * 
      from 
          (select top 5 BusinessEntityID, FirstName, LastName 
           from person.person) as a 
     ) as b
order by 
    b.BusinessEntityID desc
```

This query is giving me the last row and not the 5th row. I know this can be easily achieved with `row_number()` function but I want to know why the above query is giving the wrong output.

Comment: `SELECT TOP 5` *without* an `ORDER BY` is useless - you get an arbitrary 5 rows - since no ordering is defined. You should really define an **ordering** !

Comment: I am working on sql server 2008 r2 . Limit functionality is only from 2012 and above

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you're missing the `ORDER BY` in the `TOP 5` query. And you can remove one of the `SELECT *`

```
select top 1 * 
from (
    select top 5 BusinessEntityID,FirstName,LastName 
    from person.person
    order by BusinessEntityID asc
) as a
order by a.BusinessEntityID desc
```

Also, you are correct, this would be much simpler with `ROW_NUMBER`.